# Adding a custom class to ol or ul lists

Tags: wygwam

I'm attempting to add some sort of functionality to WYGWAM that will add a custom class to a ol or ul lists.  So for example:

```
<ol class="custom">
....
....
</ol>
```

I've tried editing a custom styleSet to something like:

```
{ name: 'Alert' , element: 'ol',attributes: { 'class': 'custom' }},
```

but this doesn't work.  It could be a Style dropdown or a custom button in the toolbar.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the instructions on creating a custom style set here http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/using/style_set.html ?

Double check that you followed those instructions. It should work just fine.

Note: If this is the only custom style in the set, or it the last in the list, then you will not need the trailing comma. If you followed the instructions above and still had a problem then that could be your issue.

Also, Chrome (and maybe other browsers) is really aggressive about caching the custom style JS file so you may need to do a hard refresh or bust the cache to load your updated style set. I usually do this by updating the reference to the styleset with a version query string `my_styles:/themes/third_party/wygwam_assets/my_styles.js?v1.2`

Comment: Thanks, I did look at that page, and is actually how I created my custom styleSet. The 'element' attribute doesn't seem to like both 'ol' and 'li' however.  I did a test by creating a new line in my styleSet with 'ol', 'li' and 'div'... only the div showed up in the dropdown list in WYGWAM.

Comment: Hmm, that's funny. I never tried it with `ol` but the CKEditor docs seem to suggest it's possible http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles

Comment: I'm running into this problem now too. can't get ul, ol, or li to work.